# Ошибка QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Делаю спамер пакетов по udp, дабы избежать заморозки интерфейса решил выделить поток, в результате получил следующее:
`Object: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread. (Parent is FileSender(0x556fd9079e80), parent's thread is QThread(0x7ffd425fea00), current thread is QThread(0x556fd8ddcae0)`

spamerwidget.cpp

```
SpamerWidget::SpamerWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::SpamerWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->pushButtonStartSpamming, &QPushButton::clicked,
            this, &SpamerWidget::slotStartSpam);

    fileSender = new FileSender();
    fileSender->moveToThread(&thread);
    connect(&thread, &QThread::started, fileSender, &FileSender::sendData);
}


SpamerWidget::~SpamerWidget()
{
    delete ui;
    delete fileSender;
}

void SpamerWidget::slotStartSpam()
{
    if (!fileSender)
        fileSender = new FileSender();

    fileSender->param.port = this->ui->portLineEdit->text().toInt();
    fileSender->param.repeatCount = this->ui->lineEditTimes->text().toInt();
    fileSender->param.delay = this->ui->editdelay->text().toDouble();
    fileSender->param.filePath = this->ui->filePathLineEdit->text();

    fileSender->sendData();
}
```

filesender.h

```
class QUdpSocket;

class FileSender : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit FileSender(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    struct parameters
    {
        int port;
        int repeatCount;
        double delay;
        QString filePath;
    }param;

    void sendData();
    void stopSendData();

public slots:
    void readyWrite();

private:
    static constexpr auto DATAGRAM_SIZE = 1464;

    using datagram = std::array<char,DATAGRAM_SIZE>;
    std::vector<datagram> datagrams;

    QFile* file;
    QEventLoop* eventLoop;
    QUdpSocket* udpSocket;
};
```

filesender.cpp

```
FileSender::FileSender(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}{ }

void FileSender::sendData()
{
    eventLoop = new QEventLoop(this);

    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, param.port);

    file = new QFile(param.filePath);
    if (file->isOpen())
        return;

    auto radioData = file->readAll();
    for(auto i = 0; i < radioData.size()/DATAGRAM_SIZE - 1; ++i)
    {
        datagram temp;
        std::copy(radioData.data() + i*DATAGRAM_SIZE,
                  radioData.data() + (i+1)*DATAGRAM_SIZE,
                  temp.begin());
        datagrams.push_back(temp);
    }

    connect(udpSocket, &QUdpSocket::bytesWritten, this, &FileSender::readyWrite);

    eventLoop->exec();
}

void FileSender::readyWrite()
{
    for(auto i = 0; i < param.repeatCount; ++i)
    {
        for(auto j = 0u; j < datagrams.size(); ++j)
        {
            udpSocket->writeDatagram(datagrams[j].data(),DATAGRAM_SIZE,QHostAddress::LocalHost, param.port);

            QThread::msleep(param.delay);
        }
    }
}
```

Я так понимаю есть всего два потока. Основной и тот что отвел я, причем же тогда родитель в другом потоке... В общем, не пойму что делаю не так.

Comment: У вас происходит следующее: переместили `FileSender` в новый поток, связали старт потока с `sendData`, поток не запускаете почему-то. Далее, видимо, нажимаете кнопку, попадаете в `slotStartSpam`, где вызывается `sendData` и создаются `QEventLoop` (зачем??) и `QUdpSocket` в главном(!) потоке (т.е. не в том, где живет их `parent - FileSender`).

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил следующим образом:
spamerwidget.h

```
class FileSender;

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class SpamerWidget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class SpamerWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    SpamerWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~SpamerWidget();


public slots:
    void slotStartSpam();

signals:
    void sendData();

private:
    Ui::SpamerWidget *ui;

    QThread thread;

    FileSender* fileSender;
};
```

spamerwidget.cpp

```
SpamerWidget::SpamerWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::SpamerWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->pushButtonStartSpamming, &QPushButton::clicked,
            this, &SpamerWidget::slotStartSpam);

    fileSender = new FileSender();
    fileSender->moveToThread(&thread);
    connect(&thread, &QThread::finished, fileSender, &QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(this, &SpamerWidget::sendData, fileSender, &FileSender::sendData);
    thread.start();
}


SpamerWidget::~SpamerWidget()
{
    delete ui;
    delete fileSender;
    thread.quit();
    thread.wait();
}

void SpamerWidget::slotStartSpam()
{
    fileSender->param.port = this->ui->portLineEdit->text().toInt();
    fileSender->param.repeatCount = this->ui->lineEditTimes->text().toInt();
    fileSender->param.delay = this->ui->editdelay->text().toDouble();
    fileSender->param.filePath = this->ui->filePathLineEdit->text();

    emit sendData();
}
```

filesender.h

```
class QEventLoop;
class QUdpSocket;

class FileSender : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FileSender(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    struct parameters
    {
        int port;
        int repeatCount;
        double delay;
        QString filePath;
    }param;

public slots:
    void sendData();

private:
    static constexpr auto DATAGRAM_SIZE = 1464;

    using datagram = std::array<char,DATAGRAM_SIZE>;
    std::vector<datagram> datagrams;

    QEventLoop* eventLoop;
    QUdpSocket* udpSocket;
};
```

filesender.cpp

```
FileSender::FileSender(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}{ }

void FileSender::sendData()
{
    eventLoop = new QEventLoop(this);

    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, param.port);

    QFile file(param.filePath);
    if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
        return;

    auto radioData = file.readAll();
    for(auto i = 0; i < radioData.size()/DATAGRAM_SIZE - 1; ++i)
    {
        datagram temp;
        std::copy(radioData.data() + i*DATAGRAM_SIZE,
                  radioData.data() + (i+1)*DATAGRAM_SIZE,
                  temp.begin());
        datagrams.push_back(temp);
    }

    for(auto i = 0; i < param.repeatCount; ++i)
    {
        for(auto j = 0u; j < datagrams.size(); ++j)
        {
            udpSocket->writeDatagram(datagrams[j].data(),DATAGRAM_SIZE,QHostAddress::LocalHost, param.port);

            QThread::msleep(param.delay);
        }
    }

    eventLoop->exec();
}
```

Добавил обработку сигнала, а также соответственно запуск потока)
Теперь интерфейс и отправка работают параллельно.